# What exactly is a convex set in two dimensional space?

Tags: calculus

From the definition of convex set being a set of points where you can draw a

straight line connecting any two of these points in the set,

so isn't convex set simply implying a domain where function has no discontinuity?

Comment: A disk is convex. What function is inherently tied to a disk?

Comment: It must be a straight line and it must lie entirely within the set. The letter U is not convex in the plane because you can't connect the two end points of the shape with a straight line which lies entirely within the figure of the U.

Comment: Consider a horseshoe shape or a lune (crescent moon shape) — neither of those are convex. A triangle is convex.

Answer (score 1):

You can think like this: A set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex if for all $x,y\in A$ and $a\in[0,1]$ we have $ax+(1-a)y\in A$. 
For more general spaces you can easily find the correcty definitions.

Now, the convexity of a set doen't depend on functions, it just depend on the set and on the space you are working. If you are thinking about the function I've used at the definition above, be careful with the domain you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

A set's convexity has nothing specifically to do with any function that might be defined on it.  Heuristically, a convex set (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is simply one that has no "indentations" in its boundary; it is always either "flat" or "protruding outward."  I'm not sure that one can be any more precise without resorting to the actual definition.

ETA: A convex *function* (of one variable) is just one that is concave upward.

Comment: This is good, because OP clearly was led astray by the use of the word “convex” also for functions, which the convexity of a *set* has little to do with.